# MIPS - Create binary word of an order

Tags: programming-languages, assembly, mips

I have the following code in MIPS language:

```
lw $s5, -20($s6)

sub $t1, $s5, $t2

addi $t1, $t2, 50
```

I need to convert each order to its code:

a. in decimal
b. in hex
c. in binary 32 bits

for the first order (lw $s5, -20($s6)) I did:

a. 35 | 22 | 21 | -20

b. 23 | 16 | 15 | C

3 questions:

1) am I right ?
2) what will be the code for 32 bits binary ?
3) What are the other codes of the other 2 more orders ?

Thanks !

Comment: Looks like a home work..

Comment: This is not homework.
It is a practice for test and I just need to know if I am right in my way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the operands and the type of the instruction, there are several encoding scheme, but all of them are composed by 32 bits and the first six specify the instruction opcode (add, lw etc).

- **Register encoding**: these instructions operates only on registers. First six bits are 0, next there are three fields of five bits which specify respectively first and second source register and the destination register. Finally there are other six bits which specify the function (add, sub etc)
- **Immediate encoding**: these instruction have an operand which is a memory location. After six bits of opcode there are two fields of five bits for the first and second register, and a field of sixteen bits for the memory location.
- **Jump Encoding**: they're composed by six bits of opcode and twenty-six bits of jump destination

[This article](http://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~isg/res/mips/opcodes) explains these instructions encoding and has a list of all opcodes / function encoding in binary. Once you have determined the binary form simply convert it to decimal and hexadecimal.

**EXAMPLE:**
Suppose we want the encoding of `lw $s5, -20($s6)`. This falls into *immediate encoding* category, whose encoding is `ooooooss sssttttt iiiiiiii iiiiiiii`, with o being the opcode, s the first register, t the second register and i the constant. Looking on the table we find the opcode for `lw` is `100011`. Specifying the register's number is enough, so s is `00101` and t is `00110`. The constant (-20) is represented by 2s complement. With 20 being `10100`, its 2s complement on 16 bit is `1111111111101100`. `lw` has a *loadstore* syntax, which template is `o $t, i ($s)`, so the registers are swapped in the encoding. Therefore the instruction encoding for `lw $s5, -20($s6)` is

```
ooooooss sssttttt iiiiiiii iiiiiiii
10001100 11000101 11111111 11101100
```

or `8C C5 FF EC` (hex) and `140 197 255 236` (dec)

Comment: So if I am taking for example the order: lw $s5, -20($s6) , and the -20 number which is the offset and it is 0b1100, it will be 0b111111111100 ? and if in other field (or a positive number with any field) I need to add zeroes in left of the number to make it be in the same number of bits as it should be ?

Comment: Thanks for the example, but I think maybe you're wrong, because your op code is 140(dec) and lw's op code should be 35(dec)...

I think maybe it should be: 35    22    21    -20 (dec).. ?

Comment: @Adam D: yes, lw's opcode is 35, but last 2 bits of first byte are part of the register (you can see this right above the binary encoding, "o" is for the opcode and "s" is for the reg.